# How to install OSQA using Xampp on Windows 7 32bit?

Tags: xampp, django, python

I want to install [OSQA](http://www.osqa.net/) using [Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) on Windows 7 32bit. I've followed the instructions on [this tutorial](http://wiki.osqa.net/display/docs/Setting+up+a+development+environment+on+Windows) until the "Install the database server" section. In this section, to create a database, I've used phpMyAdmin and created a database (name: osqa; password: 1234). Now my problem is the next step, "Edit settings". In this step I don't know how to fill in the settings_local.py's fields.

I know that Apache needs `mod_wsgi.so` so, I've placed `mod_wsgi.so` into my apache modules directory and then added `LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so` to the file `httpd.conf`. Then I restarted the apache with no errors. Then I followed the next steps, but after entering `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` in my browser, I just see a blank page!

**Can someone please provide me with an instruction in full details?** Please note that I don't like to use [Bitnami osqa](http://mail.kut.ac.ir/Main/I%20would%20be%20very%20gratefull%20if%20you%20provide%20me%20with%20an%20instruction%20in%20full%20details.%20Please%20note%20that%20I%20don%27t%20like%20to%20use%20Bitnami%20osqa%20for%20some%20reasons.) for some reasons.
Unfortunately, the [official support](http://meta.osqa.net/) for OSQA is not very active in these days.

P.s.: I'm using Python 2.7.5 and Django 1.6.2. Also my OSQA source files are in `C:\xampp\htdocs\osqa`.